# Custom GidView Inside GridView Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on a multilevel grid view For taking input only.

The core concept is In parent grid, I have a template field for project name and in another template field i have child gridview. Which have a template field for work description.

The functioning is set in the way

I implemented successfully adding new row inside the Parent grid but have no idea how to  insert a new row inside child grid. my code is as

aspx code is

```
   <asp:GridView  OnRowDataBound="grid1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" runat="server" ID="grid1">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="sn#">
           <ItemTemplate>
              <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
           </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProject" ></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grid2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
                 <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <%# Container.DataItemIndex +1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>                      
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WorkDone">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtWorkDescription"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewRowGrid2" runat="server" Text="Add new row" OnClick="btnAddNewRowGrid2_Click" />
             </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewRowGrid1" runat="server" Text="Add new row" OnClick="btnAddNewRowGrid1_Click" />
  </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
  </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

`I implemented the code in this way:`

```
 private void LoadFirstGrid1Row()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProjectId", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("WorkList", typeof(List<string>)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Grids", typeof(GridView)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ProjectId"] = string.Empty;
        dr["WorkList"] = null;
        dr["Grids"] = null;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["Grid1"] = dt;
        grid1.DataSource = dt;
        grid1.DataBind();
    }


    private void AddNewRowGrid1()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if(ViewState["Grid1"] !=null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Grid1"];
            DataRow dr = null;
            if(dt.Rows.Count >0)
            {
                for(int i = 1;i<=dt.Rows.Count;i++)
                {
                    TextBox txtproject = (TextBox)grid1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtProject");
                    GridView grid2 = (GridView)grid1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("grid2");
                    var lst = new List<string>();
                    foreach(GridViewRow row in grid2.Rows)
                    {
                        TextBox txtWorkDescription = (TextBox)grid2.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("txtWorkDescription");
                        lst.Add(txtWorkDescription.Text);
                    }

                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["ProjectId"] = txtproject.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["WorkList"] = lst;
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                ViewState["Grid1"] = dt;
                grid1.DataSource = dt;
                grid1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        SetGrid1PreviousData();
    }

    private void SetGrid1PreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["Grid1"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Grid1"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox txtProject = (TextBox)grid1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtProject");
                    GridView grid2 = (GridView)grid1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("grid2");
                    var lst = new List<string>();
                    lst = null;
                    try
                    {
                        lst = (List<string>)dt.Rows[i]["WorkList"];
                        grid2.DataSource = lst;
                        grid2.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch {
                        LoadFirstGrid2Row(grid2);                            
                    }                   
                    txtProject.Text = dt.Rows[i]["ProjectId"].ToString();                        
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    protected void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView grid2 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("grid2");
            LoadFirstGrid2Row(grid2);
        }
    }

    protected void btnAddNewRowGrid1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowGrid1();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Grid2

    private void LoadFirstGrid2Row( GridView grid2)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;                       
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("WorkDescription", typeof(List<string>)));            
        dr = dt.NewRow();            
        dr["WorkDescription"] = null;          
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["Grid2"] = dt;  
        grid2.DataSource = dt;
        grid2.DataBind();

    } 
    protected void btnAddNewRowGrid2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

**Any body Suggestion plz I can i add new rows inside inner grid view**

Comment: Perhaps not particularly helpful, but I wouldn't use gridviews. There are more useful ways of achieving the same effect, such as ListView or just creating the HTML by hand.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already defined footertemplate so

```
protected void btnAddNewRowGrid2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridViewRow row = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
string workdonetxt= (row.FindControl("txtWorkDescription") as TextBox).Text;
}
```

call insert or add function and pass the value.

Example [add row in gridview](http://aspforums.net/Threads/448504/How-to-insert-data-in-Nested-GridView-using-Footer-Row-in-ASPNet/).